# How to size an absolute positioned element so that its width will be the smallest between 80% (of container) and max-content?

Tags: css, max-content

say I've got an absolute-positioned element.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="my-element">contains text</div>
</div>
```

now I want .my-element width to be the smallest between 80% (of container) and `max-content`. Something like `min(80%, max-content)`. But I can't use `max-content` with `min()`.

Also, my-element is absolute-positioned (while container is of course relative-positioned), and this maybe could further complicate things.

How to?

Comment: width: 80%;max-width: max-content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Temani Afif suggested,

```
width: 80%;
max-width: max-content;
```